# Changing text of dynamically added element

Tags: jquery

After creating a new html element

```
$('select#base_element').append('<option value="new_option" id="option_'+id+'">New option</option>');
```

How do I do:

```
$('#option_'+id).text('new text');
```

id is a global variable that get updated each time a new option is added

Below is full example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var id = 0;
function addOption() {
    $('#myselect').append('<option id="option_'+id+'" value="blah">blah '+id+'</option>');
    $('#buttons').append('<input type="button" onclick="changeText('+id+');" value="Change text of option '+id+'" />');
    id += 1;
}

function changeText(target_id) {
        alert('Change Text clicked');
    $('#option_'+id).text('New text for option '+target_id);
}

$(function() {
    addOption();
    addOption();
    addOption();
});
</script>
<head>
<body>
<select id="myselect">

</select>
<div id="buttons"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `:` in your selector, and what is `id`?

Comment: `$(body).find('#option_' + id).text('new text');`.

Comment: : was a typo in my example. id is a global variable that get updated each time a new option is added

Comment: When do you want to update the text of options?

Comment: Try $('select #option_'+id).text('new text');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$('select #option_'+id).text('New text');  //you can use html in place of text
```

Comment: You have missed the `#` in the selector, also what is the difference between this and OP's code? and `text()` is a method not a property.

Comment: I just edited...please notice it.by overlook i didnt noticed them but i coorected

Comment: Okay, that's weird that your code solves the OP's issue, I didn't downvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

***try this***

```
html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var id = 0;
function addOption() {
    $('#myselect').append('<option id="option_'+id+'" value="blah">blah '+id+'</option>');
    $('#buttons').append('<input type="button" onclick="changeText('+id+');" value="Change text of option '+id+'" />');
    id += 1;
}

function changeText(target_id) {
// the modification is here

      $('select#myselect').find('#option_'+target_id).text('New text for option ');
}

$(function() {
    addOption();
    addOption();
    addOption();
});
</script>
<head>
<body>
<select id="myselect">

</select>
<div id="buttons"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NWMsF/7/)**

Comment: @Timothy Clemans is that working? i added a simple modification please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the contents of your element to anything you want using

```
$('#option_'+id).html('new text or html');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done complete bins for above issue. so try as demo script link as below:

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7g

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="btnadd" value="Add Option" />
<br/>
<select id="myselect">
</select>
<div id="buttons">
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var id = 0;
$(function() {
    $("#btnadd").click(function() {
        addOption();
    });
});

function addOption() {
    id += 1;
    $('#myselect').append('<option id="option_' + id + '" value="blah">blah ' + id + '</option>');
    $('#buttons').append('<input type="button" onclick="changeText(' + id + ');" value="Change text of option ' + id + '" />');
}

function changeText(target_id) {
    // Need to correction is here
    $('#myselect #option_' + target_id).text('New text for option #' + target_id);
    //OR
    // $('#myselect #option_' + target_id).html('New text for option #' + target_id);
}
```

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7g